# Sorting items in list view just work in detail view

Tags: sorting, listview

I use this code to sorting items in list view control, but it just work in detail view , for other views nothing happened. did I missing something?
Note:FileListItem  is a class inherit from ListViewItem.

```
public class ListViewItemComparer : IComparer
        {
            private SortOrder sortOrderAcDe;
            private SortBy sortByProperty;
            //
            public ListViewItemComparer(SortOrder sortOrder, SortBy sortBy)
            {
                sortOrderAcDe = sortOrder;
                sortByProperty = sortBy;
            }
            //
            public int Compare(object x, object y)
            {
                FileListItem itemX = (FileListItem)x;
                FileListItem itemY = (FileListItem)y;

                int result = 0;

                //x is directory , y is file
                if (itemX.IsDirectory && !itemY.IsDirectory)
                {
                    return -1;
                }

                //x is file , y is directory
                if (!itemX.IsDirectory && itemY.IsDirectory)
                {
                    return 1;
                }

                //both are directories
                if (itemX.IsDirectory)
                {
                    switch (sortByProperty)
                    {
                        case SortBy.Name:
                            result = String.Compare(itemX.Name, itemY.Name, false);
                            break;

                        case SortBy.Size:
                            result = String.Compare(itemX.Name, itemY.Name, false);
                            break;


                    }//switch
                }//if

                //both are files
                if (!itemX.IsDirectory)
                {
                    switch (sortByProperty)
                    {
                        case SortBy.Name:
                            result = String.Compare(itemX.Name, itemY.Name, false);
                            break;

                        case SortBy.Size:
                            result = CompareLong(itemX.Size, itemY.Size);
                            break;

                    }//switch
                }//if

                //ifDescending
                if (sortOrderAcDe == SortOrder.Descending)
                {
                    result = -result;
                }

                //return
                return result;
            }
            //
            private int CompareLong(long x, long y)
            {
                if (x < y)
                    return -1;

                if (x > y)
                    return 1;

                return 0;
            }
        }
```

then I use this code for calling

```
 public void SortItems(SortOrder sortOrder, SortBy sortBy)
    {
        this.ListViewItemSorter = new ListViewItemComparer(sortOrder, sortBy);
    }
```